# Interaction problems (too slow)

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-fragments, fragment

I have a view pager containing a main fragment and a history fragment.

When the history fragment is empty, I set an image there using `setBackgroudResource`, but then the UI is incredibly slow.

The swipes, the gestures, the events. What can be there reason for it?

I tried compressing the PNG image file multiple times, so it's probably not because of the file size.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
{ 
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_history, container, false );

    histroyListAdapter = new PasswordAdapter( historyList );
    setListAdapter(histroyListAdapter);

    noHistoryImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.noHistroySign );
    putSignIfEmpty();
    ....
}


 .......

private void putSignIfEmpty()
{
     if( historyList.isEmpty() )
     {
        noHistoryImage.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
     }
     else
     {
        noHistoryImage.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
     }
}
```

Comment: well it's a lot of code. What specific parts should I post?

Comment: Start with where you add the image resource

Comment: @DavidM edited the original post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

ok I've fixed the problem.
If anyone ever stumbles across such an issue , the solution is to copy the image to a more applicable Drawable folder.

In my case, I placed the image only in drawable-hopi at first, then I've noticed that the Eclipse emulator works perfectly ,but my phone with 1080p resolution gets sluggish, so I just copied the image to the drawable-xxhdpi and it solved it.